# Unable to find signingReport from Gradle script to find SHA-1 fingerprint key in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I am working on Flutter application and want to locate SHA-1 key. I opened android directory in Android Studio but the gradle section is not showing signingReport option.

Here is the screenshot of my android studio.

[image]

Comment: I did check this answer but the gradle bar not showing gradle scripts like that given in the screenshot of answer. There is not folder like Taks=>android=>signingReport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this command:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```